# Unable to create a linked server from sql server to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, connection

I am trying to create a linked server from sql server to mysql (remote)

Steps I followed are as follows

1. created a system dsn using 32bit odbc.

Note :

I am using windows 7, 64 bit. I installed 32 bit mysql odbc and created a new entry in the system dsn
I ran the odbc C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32 and the driver is added correctly
I also tested the connection while creating the System DSN and the connection was successful

2. In the sql server, I created the linked server, using the the system dsn i created in step 1.
3. In the security tab I used, "Be made using security context" and entered the login credentials.

Note : I made sure the system DSN and "datasource" value in the linked server have the same names

4. And when I try to connect, I get the error 7303 - datasource name not found and no default driver specified

I failed to find a solution for the same

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Regards
Rathi

Comment: Is your SQL Server 32 bit as well? If not, try making a 64 bit odbc dsn instead of the 32 bit one. Just because MySQL is 32 bit doesn't mean your dsn has to be 32 bit.

Comment: There are some instructions over on [SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic340912-146-1.aspx).  I haven't posted this as an answer because I'm not able to test at the moment.

Comment: Yes,sql server is 64 bit . And when I changed to 64 bit, it worked